# C break in for loop for no reason

Tags: c, loops, breakpoints, break

So this is a simple C code that should only exit from the loop when i press any other key except "i" or "e", but for some reason even if you press "i" or "e" the program enters the last else statement. I really don't know why this is happening, i've tried using while instead of for, and getchar instead of scanf but it still won't work. The "printf("$");"
at the end is to show me that it reaches that else statement.
   Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening?

```
for(;;)
{
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if(c=='i')
    {
        printf("insert\n");
    }
    else if(c=='e')
    {
        printf("elim\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("$");
                    break;                        
    }

}
```

Comment: I would add printf("Inserted %c",c) or something else to see what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the default behavior for `%c` in scanf -- it sees the newline and treats it as a character.  To override that, put a space before the %c in your format:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Comment: @BogdanIancu If you are using linux or osx, you can run `man 3 scanf` and see the documentation.  On scanf, it reads: c   matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1); ... The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format."

Answer (score 2):

The function will get a `\n` at the end of each line you typed.

Answer (score -2):

May be `char c` is having any other value as input stream is not flushed so `scanf` is reading other character not character you are giving .. so try `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @1'' said it all, people should stop propagating such myth.